# Subnormal Weighted shift and First order derivative

Tags: measure-theory, operator-theory

Let $\mathbb B^m$ denote the Eucledian ball in $\mathbb C^m.$ Does there exist a reinhardt measure $\mu$ supported on $\partial \mathbb B^m,$ the boundary of ball, so that the Hilber space $H^2(\mu)$, closure of the all polynomial in $m$ variable, in $L^2(\mu)$ becomes a Reproducing Kernel Hilbert space with kernel $K$ having the following property

1.$ K(0,0)=1$

2.$\partial_{z_i}\bar{\partial}_{z_j}(K(z,z)|_{z=0} = \delta_{i,j}?$

I know the answer for $m=1$ case. The usual Hardy space with Szego kernel $S(z,w) = \frac{1}{1-z\bar w}$, serves the purpose. In fact I suspect, in this case, this is the only one. But in genral when $m > 1,$ the kernel for the Hardy space is of the form $$K(z,w)= \frac{1}{(1- \langle z, w \rangle )^m}$$ But here in this case, we have $\partial_{z_i}\bar{\partial}_{z_j}(K(z,z)|_{z=0} = m \delta_{i,j}.$ But if we consider the Kernel function $K(z,w)= \frac{1}{1-\langle z, w \rangle},$ then the problem is it don't arise from any measure supported on $\partial \mathbb B^m.$ At this point I am stuck.

Any help or comment would be great.

Comment: Now also asked on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/239804/multivariable-weighted-shift-and-subnormality

Comment: BTW it is customary to wait a bit longer before posting the same question on another site. You might have a look at some posts on meta about [meta-tag:cross-posting]. For example, [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) gives some reasonable information.

Comment: @Martin okay, I will keep that in mind in future.